# The parameter is explicitly annotated as being Nullable. Either the use of the parameter or the annotation is wrong

Tags: java, sonarqube, custom-validators

When below code is run for bugs in Sonarqube

```
@Component
public class SMOCreateSignObjectValidator implements Validator{

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SMOCreateSignObjectValidator.class);
@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
    LOG.info("Inside create Sign Object validator");
    return AgreementRecordRequest.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);

}

@Override
public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {

    AgreementRecordRequest agreementRecordRequest = (AgreementRecordRequest)target;
    if(null==agreementRecordRequest.getCustomerId() || agreementRecordRequest.getCustomerId().replaceAll("\"", "").length()==0 ){
        throw new SystemException(SMOErrorConstants.MESSAGE_SMO_0003_MSG);
    }
    if(agreementRecordRequest.getExpiryDate().isEmpty()){
        throw new SystemException(SMOErrorConstants.MESSAGE_SMO_0004_MSG); 
    }
}
```

}

the following error is thrown in sonarcube.
[sonarqube screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjRLl.png)

"target must be non-null but is marked as nullable"

I have not explicitly added any annotation,Why am i getting this error?

Comment: Is it declared in `AgreementRecordRequest`?

Comment: Is the `target` parameter of `Validator` annotated with `Nullable`?  It is conceivable that sonarqube applies the interface's annotation to the implementation, and then transfers it to your `agreementRecordRequest` with the assignment.  And although that makes the diagnostic a bit cryptic, if that's indeed what is happening then it is an appropriate thing to do.

Comment: No nullable markings in Validator?

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning target parameter by class-casting to other reference. For this reason, you might get an exception. You have to control it which is null or not null or you have to add notnull annotation.

Comment: But this does not seem to address the main question of why sonarqube claims that local variable `agreementRecordRequest` is explicitly annotated Nullable, when no such annotation is present in the code provided by the OP.

Comment: But sonarqube read your code and saw it there might null pointer exception in that assignment. And thinks that it should not be null. so you have to add not null annotation. Default is nullable.